# How to implicitly convert returned value to base class without invoking copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider two classes such as these:

```
#include <cstdio>

using std::puts;

class Base {
public:
    Base() { puts("Create base"); }
    Base(const Base &) { puts("Copy base"); }
    Base(Base &&) { puts("Move base"); }
    virtual ~Base() { puts("Delete base"); }
    Base & operator=(const Base &) = delete;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { puts("Create derived"); }
    Derived(const Derived &) { puts("Copy derived"); }
    Derived(const Base &) { puts("Copy derived from base"); }
    Derived(Derived &&) { puts("Move derived"); }
    Derived(Base &&) { puts("Move derived from base"); }
    virtual ~Derived() { puts("Delete derived"); }
    Derived & operator=(const Derived &) = delete;
};
```

and a function:

```
Base fn() {
    Derived d;
    // Fill in d here
    return d;
}
```

Copying the base class is a very expensive operation, however because the derived class is not much different, it could be converted into a base object using move semantics. However, I can't get the compiler to use that implicitly instead of the copy construction. I tried adding the following with no success:

```
Base::Base(Derived &&);
Derived::operator Base &&() &&;
Derived::operator Base() &&;
```

Is there a way to avoid the copy constructor by only changing the two classes and not the function `fn`?

**EDIT: I know how to do it if I could change the function `fn` but I can't.**

Comment: Use a pointer, a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` preferably.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but have you tried returning `std::move(d)`, combined with the `Base::Base(Derived &&)` ?

Comment: No. The question is how to do it without changing the function.

Comment: @Detheroc Your function doesn't make any sense as is. You'll never get an instance of `Derived` as an lvalue result there, no matter what you do. As mentioned use a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` as return value.

Comment: Can you explain why the function return type is `Base`, but the actual object being returned is a `Derived`?   The caller will only ever see a `Base`, so the implementation of `fn()` is asking for the object to be sliced and copied.    The caller is not going to receive an object which will behave like a `Derived` in anyway.

Comment: @Peter It's common for _Factory_ patterns.

Comment: I didn't write the function, this is just a minimal example.

Comment: The logic behind it is that `Derived` has certain methods that allow to modify it in certain ways which is only allowed during construction, but not after it is returned.

Comment: Sigh, it'd be nice if requirements like *I can't modify `fn`* were given upfront.

Comment: @StoryTeller They were (just not in bold).

Comment: No they weren't, you edited them in 8 minutes in. As I was providing an answer to your **original** question.

Comment: No, the original question is the last sentence above the edit.

Comment: Then why edit if it was obviously so clear? I would say the edit is an admission to lack of clarity. But I digress. How exactly did `Base::Base(Derived &&);` result in "no success"?

Comment: @StoryTeller I edited it because people immediately started suggesting changing `fn`. No success because it still caused `Base`'s copy constructor to be called even with this move constructor present.

Comment: And how did you implement said c'tor? You'll pardon my lack of faith, but given there is no [mcve], I must ask.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - not in C++, involving a function that returns an object, which is not a wrapper for a pointer or a reference,  by value.

Comment: @Peter Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base::Base(Derived &&);` would work fine if added correctly.

```
#include <utility>

class Derived;
class Base {
  // ...
  Base(Derived &&);
};

// Derived here

Base::Base(Derived &&d) : Base(std::forward<Base>(d)) {}
```

The only tricky part is `std::forward<Base>(d)`. But it's just a cast ultimately, where we are asking to forward `d` as a `Base` xvalue. Then the delegated move constructor does the right thing.

**[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89e5767fe2f28f1b)**

RVO is guaranteed to try and return the local variable as though it was an rvalue first. Since now there is a constructor matching it, it will work.

Comment: Alright, I was testing it on [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php) and it does't work there for some reason.

Comment: Why `forward` instead of `move`?

Comment: @Fureeish -  Because we want to delegate to the c'tor taking a `Base&&`. `move` will just recurse because we'll be passing a `Derived&&`.

Comment: I see. Thank you